How to define the index of a Fredholm operator between Hilbert $ A $ - modules?
Let $A$ be a $C^*$ - algebra. ( unital or non unital )
In their book : Classifying space for proper actions and K - theory of group $C^*$-algebras, pages, $10$ and $11$, Connes, Baum, and, Higson say that we can define for each Fredholm operator $ \mathcal{F} $ between Hilbert $A$ - modules two kind of indexes, $ \mathrm{Ind}_0 ( \mathcal{F} ) \in K_0 (A) $ and, $ \mathrm{Ind}_1 ( \mathcal{F} ) \in K_1 (A) $.
Can you tell me, how are $ \mathrm{Ind}_0 ( \mathcal{F} ) $ and $ \mathrm{Ind}_1 ( \mathcal{F} ) $ explicitly defined ?
For $ \mathrm{Ind}_0 ( \mathcal{F} ) $, i know, following the book mentionned above, that it is defined as follows, $$ \mathrm{Ind}_0 ( \mathcal{F} ) = [ \mathrm{ker} (\mathcal{F})] - [ \mathrm{coker} (\mathcal{F})] \in K_0 (A)$$ but, is there a mistake in this book mentionned above, when it says that, $ \mathrm{Ind}_0 ( \mathcal{F} ) = [ \mathrm{ker} (\mathcal{F})] - [ \mathrm{coker} (\mathcal{F})] $ instead of $ \mathrm{Ind}_0 ( \mathcal{F} ) = [p] - [q] $ with $ p,q $ two projections of $K_0(A)$. Because, $\mathrm{ker} (\mathcal{F}) $ and $ \mathrm{coker} (\mathcal{F}) $ are projective modules, but not projections. Why is it the same ?
What about, $ \mathrm{Ind}_1 ( \mathcal{F} ) $ ? How is it defined explicitly ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
